R swimmer plot error in data frame length
I know I am SO close to getting this swimmer plot in R correct, but keep having an issue where it says "Error in data.frame(id_fix, start_blank, end_blank) :
arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0
I think the error is in my ther_end and ther_start columns but I've confirmed they are numeric, without NAs, and the same length as study_id. Thank you for the help!
library(swimplot)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

#example data
study_7 <- data.frame(
  study_id = c(7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8),
  ther_type = c("S", "S", "S", "S", 
                "E", "E", "E", 
                "A", "A", "A", 
                "A", "A"),
  ther_start_date = as.Date(c("2016-02-01", "2016-02-18", "2016-02-20", 
                               "2016-02-26", "2021-03-26", "2021-10-15", 
                               "2021-11-04", "2023-08-08", "2023-09-28", 
                               "2023-10-01", "2023-12-21", "2024-03-28")),
  ther_end_date = as.Date(c("2016-02-18", "2016-02-20", "2016-02-22", 
                             "2016-03-17", "2021-09-01", "2021-11-04", 
                             "2022-07-01", "2023-09-28", "2023-10-01", 
                             "2023-12-21", "2024-03-28", "2024-09-01"))
)

#create date_start_ther variable
# Create new column date_start_ther with the earliest ther_start_date for each study_id
study_7 <- study_7 %>%
  group_by(study_id) %>%
  mutate(date_start_ther = min(ther_start_date, na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup()  # Ungroup the data

# Ensure the columns are in Date format
study_7 <- study_7 %>%
  mutate(
    ther_start_date = as.Date(ther_start_date, format = "%m/%d/%y"),
    ther_end_date = as.Date(ther_end_date, format = "%m/%d/%y"),
    date_start_ther = as.Date(date_start_ther)
  )

# Calculate the difference in years
study_7 <- study_7 %>%
  mutate(
    ther_start = as.numeric(difftime(ther_start_date, date_start_ther, units = "days")) / 365.25,
    ther_end = as.numeric(difftime(ther_end_date, date_start_ther, units = "days")) / 365.25
  )


#swimmer plot code with gap data
study_plot <- swimmer_plot(
  df = study_7,
  id = 'study_id',
  start = "ther_start",
  end = "ther_end",
  name_fill = "ther_type",
  width = 0.85,
  color = NA,
  id_order = sort(unique(study_7$study_id), decreasing = TRUE)
) + theme_bw(base_size = 20) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +
  coord_flip(clip = 'off', expand = FALSE) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))


It seems to work when you force your data to be a data.frame (instead of a tibble):  df = as.data.frame(study_7) (although your x-axis is not continuous but discrete).

This was reported 3 years ago.

Now I'm getting an error message of Error in data.frame(id_fix, start_blank, end_blank) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0 when I add more than 1 study ID to the same code... any suggestions?!
